# Combing "previous row" of same table and JOIN from different table in Sqlite

Tags: sqlite, join, left-join, window-functions

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE "shots" (
    "player"    INTEGER,
    "tournament"    TEXT,
    "year"  INTEGER,
    "course"    INTEGER,
    "round" INTEGER,
    "hole"  INTEGER,
    "shot"  INTEGER,
    "text"  TEXT,
    "distance"  REAL,
    "x" TEXT,
    "y" TEXT,
    "z" TEXT
);
```

With a sample of the data:

```
28237   470 2015    717 1   1   1   Shot 1 302 yds to left fairway, 257 yds to hole 10874   11451.596   10623.774   78.251
28237   470 2015    717 1   1   2   Shot 2 234 yds to right fairway, 71 ft to hole  8437    12150.454   10700.381   86.035
28237   470 2015    717 1   1   3   Shot 3 70 ft to green, 4 ft to hole 838 12215.728   10725.134   88.408
28237   470 2015    717 1   1   4   Shot 4 in the hole  46  12215.1 10729.1 88.371
28237   470 2015    717 1   2   1   Shot 1 199 yds to green, 29 ft to hole  7162    12776.03    10398.086   91.017
28237   470 2015    717 1   2   2   Shot 2 putt 26 ft 7 in., 2 ft 4 in. to hole 319 12749.444   10398.854   90.998
28237   470 2015    717 1   2   3   Shot 3 in the hole  28  12747.3 10397.6 91.027
28237   470 2015    717 1   3   1   Shot 1 296 yds to left intermediate, 204 yds to hole    10651   12596.857   9448.27 94.296
28237   470 2015    717 1   3   2   Shot 2 208 yds to green, 15 ft to hole  7478    12571.0 8825.648    94.673
28237   470 2015    717 1   3   3   Shot 3 putt 17 ft 6 in., 2 ft 5 in. to hole 210 12561.831   8840.539    94.362
```

I want to get for each `shot` the previous location (`x`, `y`, `z`). I wrote the below query.

```
SELECT cur.player, cur.tournament, cur.year, cur.course, cur.round, cur.hole, cur.shot, cur.x, cur.y, cur.z, prev.x, prev.y, prev.z
FROM shots cur
INNER JOIN shots prev 
ON (cur.player, cur.tournament, cur.year, cur.course, cur.round, cur.hole, cur.shot) =
   (prev.player, prev.tournament, prev.year, prev.course, prev.round, prev.hole, prev.shot - 1)
```

This query takes forever basically. How can I rewrite it to make it faster?
In addition, I need to make an adjustment for the first shot on a hole (`shot` = 1). This shot is made from `tee_x`, `tee_y` and `tee_z`. These values are available in table `holes`

```
CREATE TABLE "holes" (
        "tournament"    TEXT,
        "year"  INTEGER,
        "course"    INTEGER,
        "round" INTEGER,
        "hole"  INTEGER,
        "tee_x" TEXT,
        "tee_y" TEXT,
        "tee_z" TEXT
    );
```

With data:

```
   470  2015    717 1   1   11450   10625   78.25
   470  2015    717 1   2   12750   10400   91
   470  2015    717 1   3   2565    8840.5  95
```

Thanks

Comment: There is no "previous" in an SQL table. No such thing exists. A table is a set of rows, not a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need a composite [index](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html) to speed up the operation:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_shots ON shots (player, tournament, year, course, round, hole, shot);
```

With that index, your query should run faster:

```
SELECT cur.player, cur.tournament, cur.year, cur.course, cur.round, cur.hole, cur.shot, cur.x, cur.y, cur.z, 
       prev.x AS prev_x, prev.y AS prev_y, prev.z AS prev_z
FROM shots cur LEFT JOIN shots prev 
ON (cur.player, cur.tournament, cur.year, cur.course, cur.round, cur.hole, cur.shot) =
   (prev.player, prev.tournament, prev.year, prev.course, prev.round, prev.hole, prev.shot + 1);
```

The changes I made:

- the join should be a `LEFT` join so that all rows are included and
  not only the ones that have a previous row
- `-1` should be `+1` because the previous row's shot is 1 less than the current row's shot
- added aliases for the previous row's `x`, `y` and `z`

But, if your version of SQLite is 3.25.0+ it would be better to use window function `LAG()` instead of a self join:

```
SELECT *,
       LAG(x) OVER w AS prev_x,
       LAG(y) OVER w AS prev_y,
       LAG(z) OVER w AS prev_z
FROM shots
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY player, tournament, year, course, round, hole ORDER BY shot);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/BOhnDOZ1) (I include the query plan for both queries where you can see the use of the composite index).

Comment: Thanks! If I add `prev_x`, `prev_y` and `prev_z` to `shots` how do I update the table? I tried the following (https://dbfiddle.uk/hvI6P7fb) but although sqlite says there are x rows affected the columns are still blank?

Comment: @HJA24 for this you need a correlated subquery:  https://dbfiddle.uk/7ecTnLry